# Change product category heading tag for shortcode ux_product_categories on Flatsome - Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm looking to change heading tag (currently H5) for product categories displaying on home page. These categories are displayed on home page by using an element named ux_product_categories on Flatsome theme.

It seems to be a shortcode. So I looked at product_categories.php file in wp-content/themes/flatsome/inc/shortcodes.
Indeed, I found H5 heading tag, however, when I change it (by putting the modified file with the same path in child theme)... Nothing happens, product categories have still H5 heading tag.
What do I missed ?

Here's the code I changed (replacing "h5" by "p") :

```
   <div class="box-text <?php echo implode(' ', $classes_text); ?>" <?php echo get_shortcode_inline_css($css_args); ?>>
          <div class="box-text-inner">
              <h5 class="uppercase header-title">
                      <?php echo $category->name; ?>
              </h5>
```

Comment: have you saved file?

Comment: Yes, of course. Therefore, I'm starting to wonder if it's the good file or not... But I don't know which other one it could be.
Maybe it can be solved by adding a hook in functions.php file, but I didn't learn to code...